# Perl web service : Using XML RPC

Tags: mysql, web-services, perl, xml-rpc

Something is wrong with this code.

```
#!/use/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Frontier::Daemon;
use DBI;

sub credentials {
    my ($username, $password) = @_;

    my $tablename = "users";
    my $user      = "db_user";
    my $pw        = "db_pass";

    $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database;host=localhost', $user, $pw, {RaiseError => 1});
    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM $tablename";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

    if ($sth->rows > 0) {
        $login_response = "Login Successful";
    } else {
        $login_response = "Invalid Credentials";
        return {'login' => $login_response};
        die();
    }
}

$methods = {'login.credentials' => \&credentials,};
Frontier::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 8080, methods => $methods)
  or die "Couldn't start HTTP server: $!";
```

Comment: Do I need a WHERE clause in the MYSQL statement to fetch the value of the credentials or what?

Comment: The SELECT you have return all rows from table `users`, each having columns named `username` and `password`. If you want to test specific username, you certainly should use something like `WHERE username=?` and add `$username` into `execute` call.

Comment: @bvr @chambwez I think my code is working fine now :) My last question would be, is session handling possible in XMLRPC? How do I maintain a stateful transmission between the client and the server?

Comment: In prior experience, because it's reasonably simple, we have always done this by passing an API key around with each call. For example: some.method(api_key, arguments). Another option is to use basic HTTP authentication and apply that to each call. Though special consideration should be taken if the calls are going to originate from 3rd party networks - in this instance you may wish to allow calls over SSL only to protect any credentials or data being passed in plain text.

Comment: @chambez, I was thinking about passing the key as well, but wasn't sure if it was the best route to take. please read my comment in your last post

Answer (score 2):

This is another problem with your code - you're not doing anything with the supplied username and password. You need to add a where clause to your SQL statement, so:

```
my $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($username, $password);
```

However, given that your example is selecting all records from the 'users' table, I'd have thought that credentials() would at least be returning some rows. However, I'm afraid that I've not used Frontier::Daemon in the past, so I'm not able to help on that front.

I also can't see how this code would work given that you are using strictures. $dbh, $sql, $sth and $login_response haven't been declared. So make sure that you're using 'my' in the right places - as per my example above.

To fix the problems you mentioned with returning the correct string - the logic in your if statement isn't quite right. You are returning the string 'Login Successful' when there's a successful login and the hashref { login => $login_response } when no user could be found.

I think the confusion arose from the layout of the braces. I must stress that you try and indent you code properly, which will make it much more readable to yourself and other developers when debugging and maintaining the code in the future.

The following logic should do the job.

```
  if($sth->rows > 0){
       return "Login Successful";
  }

  return "Invalid Credentials";
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I am receiving "Login Successful" if the credentials are correct. Instead of "Invalid Credentials when the login details are wrong, it outputs HASH(0x34bc764). Any reason why that's displaying?

Comment: I've added a little explanation about the if statement problem you're having with regards to your comment. Good luck!

Comment: @chambez, Thank you for the observation. I have a working system as we speak :-) even though am putting together the final section which is the SMS sending part. Am using Net::SMPP, but there seem to be little or no straight forward implementation. I have used SMPP in the past though, but in PHP